# replacing random list entries with 0

Tags: python, list, random

Hellow. I have some trouble with this question:

1. i have a list, for example `a=[1,4,5,7,10]`
2. i need another list with randomly chosen elements from **a** `(b =     np.random.choice(a,3,replace=False)` ->  b = [4,7,10]

But the length of the **b** must be the same as `len(a)`. I guess i confuse someone with that text, so here are example :

```
 1. `a = [1,4,5,7,10]` 
 2. `b = [0,4,0,7,10]`
```

so, the elements that wasn't chosen must be zeros.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Reverse the question to *"replacing random list entries with `0`"*. Then the question becomes how to decide for any value whether to set it to `0` or not. Do you want to end up with a specific number of non-`0` values, or is there a certain chance for each value to become `0`?

Comment: yeah, your logic seems to be much more pytonic than my. There are random chance for each value to become 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There'll be better solutions, but this can work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,4,5,7,10])
b = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(a)), 3, replace=False)
out = np.zeros(len(a), dtype=np.int)
out[b] = a[b]
print(out)
```

Note that I'm using `choice` on the list of indices into `a`, not the actual values of `a`.

Comment: Question is not tagged `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the question to *"replacing random list entries with 0".* Then the question becomes how to decide for any value whether to set it to 0 or not. Here we're using a certain random chance per value; you'll want to substitute that with whatever other specific criterion you have:

```
import random

a = [1,4,5,7,10]
b = [0 if random.randint(0, len(a)) < 2 else i for i in a]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

a = [1, 4, 5, 7, 10]
b = random.sample(a, len(a))

for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] != a[i]:
        b[i] = 0

print('a:', a)
print('b:', b)
```

Comment: It's rather likely that this doesn't do anything.

Comment: Now it's rather likely that it sets everything to `0`.

Comment: Sorry, my answer before the edit did not work. Now it should work.